# How to determine column width in word by openxml

Tags: openxml

I need create a word file and insert a grid in it by openxml.
So far, I know create grid like below will set the table width fit to window

```
TableProperties tblProps = new TableProperties();

tableWidth = new TableWidth() { Width = "5000", Type =TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle() { Val = "TableGrid" };
tblProps.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);

table.Append(tblProps);
```

But how can I divide a row into some columns whose share same width. Because I don't know the width of the table, so I can't calculate the width of the columns.
And the column number in different row may be different.

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Please add a tag for the language like "C#"

Comment: "I don't know the width of the table" -> `Width = "5000"` ???